# How can I compare an array of date with current date in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to compare and filter an array of dates with current date in nodejs like if the date is greater than or equal to the current date or less than the current date

Comment: Show us your data and the code you tried to come up with so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use [moment JS](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/). So you can easily compare :

```
moment('2010-10-20').isSameOrAfter('2010-10-19'); // true
moment('2010-10-20').isSameOrAfter('2010-10-20'); // true
moment('2010-10-20').isSameOrAfter('2010-10-21'); // false
```

you can call

```
moment()
```

to get current date.

Answer (score 0):

May be it can help you.

```
var multi = [
    {
      "name": "test1",
      "series": [
        {
            "date": new Date("2018-01-01T01:10:00Z"),
            "value": 44
        },...
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "series": [
        {
            "date": new Date("2018-01-01T01:10:00Z"),
            "value": 38
          },...
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "test3",
      "series": [
        {
            "date": new Date("2018-01-01T01:10:00Z"),
            "value": 33
          },...
      ]
    }
  ];


multi.series = multi.series.filter((item: any) => {
    return item.date.getTime() >= fromDate.getTime() &&
           item.date.getTime() <= toDate.getTime();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example. It will give the difference of dates in miliseconds.

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
var mydatestring = '2020-03-15T09:29:05.00';
var oldDate = new Date(mydatestring);

var difference = currentDate - oldDate; 
console.log(difference)
```